# Bernoulli monosplines

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series, spline

Please help me with Bernoulli monosplines. Let's consider $2\pi$-periodic cubic spline, which is consist from $N$ ranges $0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_N<2\pi$. We can introduce a periodic function on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ by the formula:
$$
D(u)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ku)}{k^4}.
$$
For any spline $s \in S^{N}$ we can be unambiguously calculate breaks of the third derivative in the nodes of our grid. Spline is a polynomial of the third degree between nodes of grid, and the third derivative between nodes is constant. We can introduce the following notation:
$$
\beta_i = s'''(u_i+0)-s'''(u_i-0); i = 1,\ldots,N; \beta_0 = 0
$$
According [Korneychuk, N.P., Splines in the Theory of Approximation], breaks of the third derivative at the nodes define the spline accurate to the integral over the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$:
$$
s(u) = \beta_0 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \beta_i D(u-u_i) \tag{$*$}
$$
I want to recostruct any $2\pi$-periodic function by representing expression. I programmed this algorithm at Matlab, but the problem is that the function $s(u) = \sin(u)$ is perfectly reconstructed with the help of (*), but other functions, such as $s(u) = \cos(u)$, does not reconstruct correctly. 
Thank you.

Comment: In the context of (\*), the function $u$ is a piecewise cubic polynomial and $\beta_i$ are the jumps of its third derivative. How are you applying (\*) to $s(u)=\sin (u)$ or $s(u)=\cos (u)$, which are not  cubic splines?

Comment: I mean, that $s(u)$ is any function that "glued" from pieces of cubic polynomials.So I define $s(u)$ by discrete values, for eample $s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{20}$  in points $0<u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{20}<2\pi$. After that I calculate cubic polinomial in intervals $u_0<u_1;u_1<u_2;u_2<u_3;...;u_{19}<u_{20}$. After that I calculate jumps of third derivative of each cubic polynomial in points $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{19}$ and put calculated values in $\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_{19}$. After that I am applying (*) using $\beta_i$ and $u_i$ where $i=1,2,\ldots,19$.

Comment: This formula (*) calculate interpolated value of initial function $s(u)$ in any $u\in[0,2\pi]$.